# As of right now, on Windows 7, does Mercurial start up a server much simpler than Git?

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs, git-daemon

On Windows 7, from reading hginit.com, it seems like it is very easy to set up a Mercurial server?

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
hg init
hg serve
```

and that's it?  Now http://localhost:8000 is the server.  It seems that it is quite a bit harder to set a Git server up, either for Cygwin and mysysGit?  Git for sure will make it simpler, maybe just not at this moment...

Comment: Git is pretty much Unix-alike software only.  You can hack it to kinda/sorta work in Windows but it does not even begin to try to feel natural in that environment.

Comment: JMCO... god, we need to make it into an official acronym...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having attempted to get a Git server running on Windows using [gitosis](http://www.shannoncornish.com/blog/2009/04/gitosis-windows-server-2008/), I can attest that:

"hg serve"

is vastly more straightforward!

**Update**

Hopefully [Smart HTTP Support](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) in Git will make this more straightforward, but of course will depend on how it is made available if we are comparing it to the ease of "hg serve".

**Update 2**

If all you want to do is quickly share a repo with a colleague, then "hg serve" presents a beautifully straightforward way of doing that. Setting up a robust and secure mutli-user server is another matter for both platforms.

**Update 3**

This is a very decent start at hosting Git repositories using IIS with [Smart HTTP Support](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html). Works for me:

http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/06/25/hosting-a-git-server-under-iis7-on-windows/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, running a Mercurial server is that simple. On the other hand, we (the Mercurial developers) don't really consider hg serve a tool for long-running usage. That is, it's nice to quickly share a repo at a sprint or so, but for more robust hosting, using apache + mod_wsgi or fcgi or even just cgi is probably better.

Comment: And it's still easier to use on Windows than Git.  :D

Answer (score 2):

You can just put a bare git repo on any kind of Windows shared filesystem and use that as your server. You dont even need a running process. Security can be handled at the filesystem level.

Comment: as your server...  but can you access it through some GUI method such as on a webpage?  Can your coworker check it out remotely by this same GUI method too?

Comment: yes, expose the folder via a net share.  not necessarily secure but it does what you are asking.